# snapcraft with python plugin: returned non-zero exit status 2

Tags: python, snapcraft

I am playing a little bit with snapcraft and everything worked fine but now I get following error - I have no clue what causes the error:

> Successfully installed appdirs packaging pip-8.1.2 pyparsing-2.1.8 setuptools-26.1.1 six-1.10.0 wheel-0.29.0
>   /home/bla/bla/parts/myapp/install/usr/bin/python2 -m pip download --disable-pip-version-check --dest /home/bla/bla/parts/myapp/packages . setuptools
>   /tmp/tmps75wvcfe: 10: export: distribution/linux/Snapping/myapp/stage/usr/share/perl5/: bad variable name
>   Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmpseb6idqm', '/home/bla/bla/parts/myapp/install/usr/bin/python2', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--disable-pip-version-check', '--dest', '/home/bla/bla/parts/myapp/packages', '.', 'sqlalchemy']' returned non-zero exit status 2

My snapcraft.yaml file:

```
name: myapp
version: "1.0"
summary: myapp snap test
confinement: devmode
grade: devel

apps:
  myapp:
    command: myapp

parts:
  myapp:
    plugin: python
    python-version: python2
    python-packages:
     - setuptools
    source: ./src/foo
    source-type: git
    stage-packages:
      - python-pyqt5
      - python-sqlalchemy
      - python-setuptools
```

Do you have any ideas what could cause the error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which seemed to be caused by space characters in the path to where I was building the snap.

My original path was:

~/Documents/Programming Projects/Python Projects/TemperaturePi

and snapcraft gave the same error.

I moved the directory to:

~/Documents/TemperaturePi

and the snap built without the above error.